# Pyright on Neovim (kickstart) puts error labels on perfectly fine code whenever I try type labeling

Tags: python, neovim, pyright

here are example of what I'm talking about :

[cannot assign 'None' as a default value to a parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po0Z9.png)

[cannot type an int 2-tuple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dplMp.png)

[other errors related to types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYWMr.png)

the code runs just fine, and other text editors don't whine about it.
i tried creating a `pyrightsconfig.json` :

```
{
    "pythonVersion": "3.10.12",
    "pythonPlatform": "Linux",
    "typeCheckingMode": "basic"
}
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

I'm using the kickstart config for neovim, it's practically unchanged.

also, is there a way to create a global pyrights config instead of doing in on a per-project basis ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `(int, int)` isn't a valid type annotation. Perhaps you meant `tuple[int, int]`.

Comment: It would be more helpful if the error messages weren't cut off in the screenshots.

Comment: yes, I meant tuple[int, int]

Comment: sorry for the screenshot, the text was cropped in my window and I didn't know how to show the rest

Comment: So Pyright was right and your code is not perfectly fine.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't make a screenshot but just run Pyright in the terminal and copy the error message and relevant code as text.

Comment: The code runs any way, but yeah I guess pyright with the current config is just stricter than other editors about typing, thanks!

Comment: pyright isn't recognised as a command in the terminal